# CSS: Overriding !important with another !important not working?

Tags: html, css, templates, joomla

I am sure I am missing something simple, but after searching for a while and not finding any answers, here's my question:

I am developing a component for Joomla!.  The component itself works fine as far as functionality goes.  What I do notice, however, is that some styling doesn't work.

- I have a table contained in a div, each having their own classes for styling purposes.
- Styling was working fine until I tested a few different templates to see their effects on my styling.
- Due to **template** styling from various templates, my tables are wider than the window (templates have `width:540px!important;` in their CSS)
- My attempt at overriding this was to add `width:100%!important;` to `<style></style>` tags in the output of the component - inside the body of the document.  This would ensure that my CSS is loaded last, which should override the CSS from the template.
- Order of CSS being loaded is as follows: In the `<head></head>` of the document: My component's CSS, and then the template CSS.  This causes my CSS to be overridden by the template.  Hence my decision to add style tags inside the body tags just above the opening div tag of my component.

The result of all this is that my CSS is indeed loaded last, from the style tags just above my component's opening div tag.  The CSS from the template, however, is still being applied over mine.

To my understanding, it's not great practice to be using !important to begin with, and overriding it with another !important is not great either.  Please do correct me if I am wrong, along with a possible answer as to how I can override the template's CSS and make sure that my component's CSS is being applied - without modifying the template directly; the component should be template independent and always work regardless of the template's styling.

Thanks in advance.

/******* EDIT ******/

Here is the code in question - in summary form (it would be overkill to include the bazillion lines of code from the template, but you are welcome to ask for more if necessary):

```
<html lang="en-gb" slick-uniqueid="3">
<head>
    <!-- Meta tags and other stuff -->

    <!-- MY CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/subdomainname/media/com_mycomponent/css/mystylesheet.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- ANNOYING TEMPLATE CSS, SNIPPET TO FOLLOW -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mydomain.co.za/subdomainname/templates/annoyingtemplate/css/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 580px)">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- template stuff as there would be in any other template, menus and modules etc -->

    <style>
    <!-- a bunch of my own CSS, none related at all to the tables in question
        @media screen and (max-width:480px)
        {
            .sortSearchFilter table 
            {
                width: 100%!important;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <div class="mycomponent">
        <!-- component HTML -->
        <div class="sortSearchFilter">
            <table>
                <!-- table contents -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have also tried giving the table it's own class and styling, that didn't go particularly well - was *still* overridden by the template :( Here is a snippet from the template CSS file mentioned above:

```
#gkMainbody table {
    width: 540px!important;
    display: block!important;
    padding: 30px 0 20px 0; /* padding for the scrollbars and the top message */
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

And here are two screen snips from chrome's inspector:

[image: Template CSS]

[image: My style tags...]

/********** SECOND EDIT ***********/

Thanks for the great advice everyone.  In the end I ended up using `min-width` *and* `max-width` in my own CSS to apply the height. Not the greatest solution but it does seem to work.  Also, I failed to notice earlier that the `tbody` in tables also had a width applied by the template, which also seemed to be messing with my styling.
Adding a class to my table still didn't help much; although adding an ID did work (by adding CSS to that ID) - although I still have to apply `!important` to the rules to make sure the template CSS is overridden.

Comment: "This would ensure that my CSS is loaded last, which should override the CSS from the template" — That isn't how CSS works. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade

Comment: `!important` should never be used reactively, only proactively.

The `!important` tag that is loaded last, aka is included last in your code, will be the one that is styled.

Comment: @user3008011 — As pointed out in the link in my previous comment, that isn't necessarily true.

Comment: Templates are using `table { width:540px!important; }`? For real? How are you applying your 100% width style in your component? Can you please show your code for this? Out of all honesty, you will never get anything perfect for every template out there as so many template developers think it's ok to use `!important` for their own use, meaning it extension developers cannot style their extensions at ease

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for the advice, I am reading up on cascading now.  If I find my solution I'll post it :)

Comment: @Lodder - I'll post my code in a moment.

Comment: Try adding a class to your table and targeting that class in the CSS

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember what works but here is what i would try:

instead of using

```
table {width:...!important}
```

use (make sure your table has an id)

```
#tableid {width:...!important}
```

Or use inline css

```
style="width:100%!important"
```

Or use div instead of table

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 ways to override an `!important` declaration with CSS :

- adding a more specific !important property : `body table { width: 100% !important;}` (for example)
- declaring the same rule, but after the one you want to override
- declaring it in the HTML element : `<table style="width:100%">`

*Note that all of this is kinda dirty.*

Comment: Thanks @enguierranws.  I have tried the more specific rule idea but that is difficult to apply as I can not afford to reference anything inside the template.  Also, using body table { ... } isn't necessarily more specific.  

I would expect the same rule being redeclared to work but it doesn't seem to be working that way so far.

Inline styling such as including the style in the element's decleration is also not really an option in this instance

Comment: Well, body table {} will allways be more specific than table {}.

Comment: I gave you the 3 options you have, now, make your choice. As we have no live exemple, no HTML code, I can't help you more.